# TypeError: Utente is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to do a user registration with a Node js app and MongoDB but I have this error:
`const utente = new Utente({  ||||| TypeError: Utente is not a constructor`

There's my model utente.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Utente = mongoose.model(
  "Utente",
  new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    nome: String,
    cognome: String,
    password: String,
    admin: String,
  })
);

module.exports = Utente;
```

There's the controller for the registration:

```
const { validationResult } = require("express-validator");
const { Utente } = require("../models/utente");

exports.registrazione = async (request, response, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(request);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return response.status(422).json({
      message: "Errore nell'Inserimento dei Dati",
      error: errors.array(),
    });
  }

  console.log("Email:", request.body.email);

  const utente = new Utente({
      email: request.body.email,
      nome: request.body.nome,
      cognome: request.body.cognome,
      password: request.body.password,
      cellulare: request.body.cellulare,
      admin: request.body.admin
  });
  
  if (utente.findOne({email: request.body.email})) {
    return response.status(400).send('Esiste già un account con questa email');
  } else {
      utente.save();

      response.status(201).json({
        messages: "Utente Registrato con Successo",
      });
  }
};
```

I tried to display the information with console.log()from the request and the information are showed correctly but I got this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as montioned in @Montgomery Watts answer either you export and import like this :

```
module.exports = Utente;
const Utente = require("../models/utente");
```

or :

```
module.exports = {Utente};
const {Utente} = require("../models/utente");
```

**Note :** either you missed `cellulare` peroperty in the model or you have put it by mistake here :

```
const utente = new Utente({
  email: request.body.email,
  nome: request.body.nome,
  cognome: request.body.cognome,
  password: request.body.password,
  cellulare: request.body.cellulare,
  admin: request.body.admin
});
```

**also :** you should use `findOne` with the `model` not with the `instance` :

```
Utente.findOne({email: request.body.email})) // Utente with uppercase U
```

Answer (score 1):

When you specify:

```
module.exports = Utente;
```

You are creating a default export. So to import the model, you would do:

```
const Utente = require("../models/utente");
```

Notice that `Utente` is not surrounded by `{ }`.

If you do want to import `Utente` the way you are currently, you would export it like this:

```
exports.Utente = Utente;
```

The controller file you shared also does this for `registrazione`.